# How do I pass a function through props to a chid component where the parent is a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The parent looks like this and needs to pass the function down to the child element so it can call it and pass information back up.

```
import './App.css';
import Item from './components/Item';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [items, setitems] = useState([...]

  const addItemToCart = item => {
    console.log(item);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul className='items'>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Item
            name={item.name}
            quantity={item.quantity}
            description={item.description}
            thumbnail={item.thumbnail}
            addItemToCart={() => addItemToCart}
          ></Item>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The child looks like this:
(the button (commented) is where the function needs to trigger on click and i need to pass information up to the other function)

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Item(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <li className='item'>
        <img src={props.thumbnail} className='item-thumbnail' />
        <h3 className='item-name'>{props.name}</h3>
        <p className='item-description'>{props.description}</p>
        <label className='item-quantity'>
          {props.quantity > 1
            ? `${props.name} come in groups of ${props.quantity}`
            : ''}
        </label>
        <button onClick={props.addItemToCart('hello')}>add item</button> // this is the button where the function needs to trigger on click and i need to pass information up to the other function
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `addItemToCart={() => addItemToCart}` should be `addItemToCart={addItemToCart}`, no ? And `onClick={props.addItemToCart('hello')}` to `onClick={() =>props.addItemToCart('hello')}`

Answer (score 2):

First in App:

```
addItemToCart={addItemToCart}
```

then, in the Item:

```
<button onClick={() => props.addItemToCart('hello')}>add item</button>
```

In the original version, the onClick would be called as:

```
('hello') => addItemToCart // ref to a function, not the call itself
```

Comment: Yes And as I mentionned, you done the same error in the item... `onClick={props.addItemToCart('hello')}` should be `onClick={() => props.addItemToCart('hello')}`

Answer (score 0):

```
addItemToCart={() => addItemToCart}
```

should be

```
addItemToCart={addItemToCart}
```

And

```
onClick={props.addItemToCart('hello')}
```

to

```
onClick={() =>props.addItemToCart('hello')}
```